# How to show date depends on from date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two datepickers. I want to show `to` date depends on `from` date. `To` date should be future date from `from date` plus 1. `From` and `To` dates are not same. `To` date always starts on the next day of `from date`.

Example:

```
If I select `from` 07/18/2018 `to` date do not like from 07/18/2018.
```

So I want to show after date of from date.

```
If I select `from` 07/18/2018 `to` date will start like from 07/19/2018.
```

If you see my JSFiddle you can understand: http://jsfiddle.net/FdfPY/771/

JavaScript:

```
  var disabledDates = []
  $(".from_date").datepicker({
  minDate: 'D',
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  numberOfMonths: 1,
        beforeShowDay: function(d) { 
        if (d.getDate() == 2 || d.getDate() == 16) {
          return [true, "" ];
        } else {
           return [false, "" ];
        }
     },
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
  disabledDates=[selectedDate];
    $(".to_date").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate); 
  }
  });

  $(".to_date").datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  numberOfMonths: 1,
        beforeShowDay: function(d) {  

        if (d.getDate() == 2 || d.getDate() == 16) {
          return [true, "" ];
        } else {
           return [false, "" ];
        }
     } 
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nested-fields row">
  <div class="span2">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label>From</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="from_date" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span2">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label>To</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="to_date" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:left"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what is not working with the given code? What have you tried to overcome what is missing?

Comment: To date it should be start next day of "from date"

Comment: Example From and to dates should not be same date..Maximum i have done but i want "To" date it should be start next day of "from date"

Comment: Sounds like a design question. You can show a validation error if the user selects a from date that is after the to date. You can prevent the user from selecting dates equal to or prior to the from date once it's been selected. There are a large number of methods to do this, all depending on your users.

Comment: please see the jsfiddle. in my calender i am showing only 2 and 16 dates for all years.i want to show future dates only depends on from date. 
     jsfiddle.net/FdfPY/770

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
var disabledDates = []
$(".from_date").datepicker({
      minDate: 'D',
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function(selectedDate) {
      disabledDates=[selectedDate];
        $(".to_date").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate); 
      }
    });

 $(".to_date").datepicker({
      minDate: 0,
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      numberOfMonths: 1,
       beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date);
        return [ disabledDates.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }

    });
```

Comment: This is my condition..I have enabled 2 and 16 day on every month. http://jsfiddle.net/FdfPY/563/

Comment: That is my condition..I want to show only 2 and 16 day of all months

Comment: @AppleOrange If you have other constraints, [edit] your question to include those.

Comment: Not working..please see the jsfiddle. in my calender i am showing only 2 and 16 dates for all years.i want to show future dates only depends on from date. jsfiddle.net/FdfPY/770